# retrieve sorted search results from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am facing a problem with elastic search. I am using elasticsearch 5.6

When I am searching an index on some fields and I get to have more than 40000 results.

I found 2 problems:

1. When trying to access page 1001 (results 10001) I get an error and I understood I can increase the default 10,000, However I can accept this limitation and expose back to the user only the first 10,000 results.
2. When I am trying to sort by a specific field, the sort does not work. This is a huge problem for me as this search is used by a client UI and I must enable paging through the results. I read about the scroll API but I does not fit my requirements (user requests from UI).

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: in which field sorting doesn't work? which datatype has this field? if you don't like the limitation of scrooll query, you could use the search after query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-search-after.html

Comment: Hi, I found the problem, the field I was trying to sort by was a nested document and the query was written wrong, it has to use the nested path, after fixing it it works well.
Anyway about the search after it is also no optimized for usage as user request

Comment: I'm glad that you have solved. why search after is no optimized for usage as user request? It is better for pagination than scroll